# bind element to events and then assgned it with function

Tags: jquery, html, ipad

i have image which i want to bind with events like touch,tap,touchStart,click and then assign it to my.Onclick ?? how to do this? i cant directly put function instead of my.Onclick because that binding is inside some loop directly putting function will make it call many times??

```
      onClick:    function {  FlipIT(this); }
       .
       .
   $('image').bind('click','touch','touchStart') =my.onClick;
```

**Actual :**

```
image.onclick = my.onClick;
```

in actual code it is like above , but onclick not working in tab thats why i want to bind it with events .

Answer (score 2):

Ui, hui ui!

You made much things completely wrong!

1. There's no `touch`-event (just `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend`, `touchcancel`)
2. The callback function has to be an argument from the `event`-handler
3. `bind` is deprecated in `jQuery v2.0.1`

Try this (and compare what you did wrong)!

```
$('image').on('click touchend', my.onClick);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88uCJ/

I recommend you to use a linting tool like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) or [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) to validate your code!

Comment: @yckart putting my.onClick inside ()   will directly calling method , i just want to assigned the event

Comment: @simmisimmi No, your function will not called until the event was fired. http://jsfiddle.net/88uCJ/

Comment: @yckart i want to just change click event ,image.onclick = my.onClick;   here only event is changed function is not called

Comment: @yckart I want something like this $(image).attr("onClick","flipIt(this)");

Comment: @yckart just now got this will test and let you know